# Поворот системы координат относительно двух точек

Tags: координаты

Допустим что у меня есть сетка координат и 2 ключевые точки, при смещении этих двух ключевых точек, сетка координат должна смещаться относительно этих точек, причём нужно учесть не только смещение по координатам но и поворот каждой точки в сетке относительно двух ключевых. То есть если ключевые точки смещаются не на одинаковое расстояние и между ними возникает наклон, каждая точка в сетке должна учесть этот наклон и так же наклониться. Какие есть инструменты для удобной манипуляции сеткой, что бы не приходилось прописывать всё самому?

Comment: геометрия и матрицы

Comment: расстояние между точками остаётся неизменным?

Comment: @MBo да, меняется только угол поворота и смещение

Comment: По этим принципам работает [transform: matrix()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/matrix) в CSS и SVG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При отсутствии масштабирования матрицу аффинного преобразования можно рассчитать так:

имеем начальные точки `(X11, Y11), (X21, Y21)`
после преобразования  `(X12, Y12), (X22, Y22)`

Угол поворота и его косинус и синус (если я не запутался в индексах)

```
Fi = atan2((X22-X12)*(Y21-Y11)-(Y22-Y12)*(X21-X11), 
           (X22-X12)*(X21-X11)+(Y22-Y12)*(Y21-Y11))
c = Cos(Fi)
s = Sin(Fi)
```

Вначале переносим начало координат в точку `(X11, Y11)`
Затем вращаем на угол `Fi`
Теперь переносим на `(X12, Y12)`
Получаем матрицу

```
[[c, -s, 0], 
 [s, c, 0], 
 [-x11*c-y11*s+x12, x11*s-y11*c+y12, 1]])
```

И в дальнейшем применяем её ко всем нужным точкам (умножаем вектор `[x,y,1]` на неё)